# does postgresql array type preserve order of array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I read over the docs for PostgreSQL v 9.3 arrays (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html), but I don't see the question of ordering covered. Can someone confirm that Postgres preserves the insertion order/original order of an array when it's inserted into an array column? This seems to be the case but I would like absolute confirmation.

Thank you.

Comment: a) I don't see explicit documentation. b) It wouldn't make sense to change the order. The example table "sal_emp" has an array of quarterly pay; if "pay_by_quarter[1]" sometimes returned the value for the first quarter and sometimes for the fourth quarter, heads would have exploded by now. AFAIK, array data types in *every* language preserves order. c) For explicit confirmation, you'll probably have to check source code or the pghacker mailing list.

Answer (score 19):

The documentation is entirely clear that arrays are useful in scenarios where order is important, inasmuch as it explicitly documents querying against specific positions within an array. If those positions were not reliable, these queries would have no meaning. (Using the word "array" is also clear on this point, being as it is a term of the art: An array is an ordered datatype *by its nature*; an unordered collection allowed to contain duplicates would be a bag, not an array, just as an unordered collection in which duplicates were not allowed would be a set).

See [the examples given in section 8.1.4.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html), of "pay by quarter", with index position within the array indicating *which* quarter is being queried against.

Answer (score -2):

Cannot find in documentation, but I'm pretty sure. Yes, order is preserved. And [2,4,5] is different from [5,2,4].

In case I'm wrong, indexes cannot work.

Comment: *"Cannot find in documentation, but I'm pretty sure."* Well, that's basically the OP's question, isn't it?